# Using Vega with Elasticsearch data containing nested aggregations (or dividing one aggregation by another in Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I'm trying to do something with Elasticsearch that should be quite simple. I have an index which contains documents of the shape: {"timestamp": int, "pricePerUnit": int, "units": int}. I want to visualize the average price over time in a histogram. Note that I don't want the average of the "pricePerUnit", I want the average price paid per unit, which means finding the total value in each time bucket by multiplying the "pricePerUnit" by the "units" for each document, and summing the total value sold in each document, then dividing by the sum of the total units sold in the time bucket to get the average price paid per unit. A standard Kibana line chart won't work. I can get the average "pricePerUnit * units", but can't divide this aggregation by the sum of the total units. Also can't be done in TSVB, as this doesn't allow for scripts/scripted fields. Can't use timelion, because the "timestamp" field isn't a time field (I know, but there's nothing I can do about it). I'm therefore trying to use Vega. However, I'm running into a problem with nested aggregations. Here's the ES query I'm running:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.json",
  
  "data": {
  "name": "vals",
      "url": {
      "index": "index_name",
      "body": {
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": 2000,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "pricePerUnit",
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc['pricePerUnit'].value * doc['units'].value",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "spend": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['pricePerUnit'].value * doc['units'].value",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "docvalue_fields": [],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timeslot.startTime": {
              "gte": 1621292400,
              "lt": 1621428349
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
},
      "format": {"property": "aggregations.2.buckets"}
    }
    }
  ,
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "vals", "field": "1.value"},
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "time",
      "range": "width"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"scale": "yscale", "orient": "left"},
    {"scale": "xscale", "orient": "bottom"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "line",
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "key"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "1.value"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It gives me the following result set:

```
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 4,
    "successful": 4,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 401,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "2": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 86340
          },
          "key": 1621316000,
          "doc_count": 7
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 231592.92307692306
          },
          "key": 1621318000,
          "doc_count": 13
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 450529.23529411765
          },
          "key": 1621320000,
          "doc_count": 17
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 956080.0555555555
          },
          "key": 1621322000,
          "doc_count": 18
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 1199865.5714285714
          },
          "key": 1621324000,
          "doc_count": 14
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 875300.7368421053
          },
          "key": 1621326000,
          "doc_count": 19
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 926738.8
          },
          "key": 1621328000,
          "doc_count": 20
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 3239475.3333333335
          },
          "key": 1621330000,
          "doc_count": 18
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 3798063.714285714
          },
          "key": 1621332000,
          "doc_count": 21
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 482089.5
          },
          "key": 1621334000,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 222952.33333333334
          },
          "key": 1621336000,
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 742225.75
          },
          "key": 1621338000,
          "doc_count": 8
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 204203.25
          },
          "key": 1621340000,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 294886
          },
          "key": 1621342000,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 284393.75
          },
          "key": 1621344000,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 462800.5
          },
          "key": 1621346000,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 233321.2
          },
          "key": 1621348000,
          "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 436757.8
          },
          "key": 1621350000,
          "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 4569021
          },
          "key": 1621352000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 368489.5
          },
          "key": 1621354000,
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 208359.4
          },
          "key": 1621356000,
          "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 7827146.375
          },
          "key": 1621358000,
          "doc_count": 8
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 63873.5
          },
          "key": 1621360000,
          "doc_count": 6
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 21300
          },
          "key": 1621364000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 138500
          },
          "key": 1621366000,
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 5872400
          },
          "key": 1621372000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 720200
          },
          "key": 1621374000,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 208634.33333333334
          },
          "key": 1621402000,
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 306248.5
          },
          "key": 1621404000,
          "doc_count": 10
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 328983.77777777775
          },
          "key": 1621406000,
          "doc_count": 18
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 1081724
          },
          "key": 1621408000,
          "doc_count": 10
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 2451076.785714286
          },
          "key": 1621410000,
          "doc_count": 14
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 1952910.2857142857
          },
          "key": 1621412000,
          "doc_count": 14
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 2294818.1875
          },
          "key": 1621414000,
          "doc_count": 16
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 2841910.388888889
          },
          "key": 1621416000,
          "doc_count": 18
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 2401278.9523809524
          },
          "key": 1621418000,
          "doc_count": 21
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 4311845.4
          },
          "key": 1621420000,
          "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 617102.5333333333
          },
          "key": 1621422000,
          "doc_count": 15
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 590469.7142857143
          },
          "key": 1621424000,
          "doc_count": 14
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 391918.85714285716
          },
          "key": 1621426000,
          "doc_count": 14
        },
        {
          "1": {
            "value": 202163.66666666666
          },
          "key": 1621428000,
          "doc_count": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can't extract the "value" field from the "1" sub-aggregation. I've tried using a flatten transform, but it doesn't seem to work. If anyone can either:

a) Tell me how to solve this specific problem with Vega; or
b) Tell me another way to solve my original problem

I'd be much obliged!

Answer (score 2):

Your DSL query is looking great. If I've read this correctly I believe what you are looking for is a [project transform](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/project/). This can make life a lot easier when dealing with nested variables, as there are certain instances  where they just don't function as expected.

You also need to reference data within marks otherwise it will plot nothing.

Below is how to fix this, you'll just need to add your url parameter in.

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.json
  data: [
    {
      name: vals
      url: ... // fill this in
      transform: [
        {
          type: project
          fields: [
            1.value
            doc_count
            key
          ]
          as: [
            val
            doc_count
            key
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  scales: [
    {
      name: yscale
      type: linear
      zero: true
      domain: {
        data: vals
        field: val
      }
      range: height
    }
    {
      name: xscale
      type: time
      domain: {
        data: vals
        field: key
      }
      range: width
    }
  ]
  axes: [
    {
      scale: yscale
      orient: left
    }
    {
      scale: xscale
      orient: bottom
    }
  ]
  marks: [
    {
      type: line
      from: {
        data: vals
      }
      encode: {
        update: {
          x: {
            scale: xscale
            field: key
          }
          y: {
            scale: yscale
            field: val
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In future if you are having issues, look at the examples found on the [Vega Gallery](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/). They also have [extensive documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/). These two combined is all you need.